# Is it possible to edit code in Visual studio and build it remotely?

Tags: linux, build, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

I have development machine on Linux. Normally I connect to it, edit some code and run my `./BuildAll.sh` script.
But now (due to poor internet ping) editing remotely is painful.

I have visual studio 2017 on my laptop and I want to achieve code editing in VS but build changed code on remote Linux.

I imagine it like this:

`I edit code in VS` `->` `push some button in VS` `->` `edited code copied to developer Linux machine` `->` `my build script runs on Linux machine` -> `I gets output of script`.

I download `Linux development with C++` toolset
I connected to my Linux machine via `menu` `->` `Tools` `->` `Cross Platform` `->` `Connection Manager`. 
I download my repo. (without *.sln inside)
And now I stuck with next step.

What I need to do or maybe it is impossible to achieve what I want with VS.

Comment: Did you check the options of using Azure DevOps or something similar? There you could setup a pipeline which builds your code and then deploys it.

Comment: I will check. Thank you for direction.